# Understanding the martingale property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales

My lecture notes says that "The idea of the martingale property is that, on average, the Markov chain stays where it is and for this to be true, the chain must stay where it is all the time (i.e. be in an absorbing state) or be able to move in both directions. This shows that, for a martingale on the state space $$S = \{0, \dots, d\},$$ the states $0$ and $d$ must be absorbing."

Intuitively, I understand why the states $0$ and $d$ must be absorbing.

However, my lecture notes then goes on to say that "For a more formal demonstration, note that the martingale property shows that $$\sum^d_{y = 0} yP(0, y) = 0$$ so that $$P(0, 1) = P(0, 2) = \dots = P(0, d - 1) = P(0, d) = 0$$ and we see that state $0$ is absorbing. A similar argument shows that state $d$ is absorbing."

This is the part that I do not quite understand yet.

**Thus, my question is, to show that state $d$ is absorbing, I can get from $$\sum^d_{y = 0} yP(d, y) = d$$ to $$P(d, 1) + 2P(d, 2) + \dots + (d - 1)P(d, d - 1) + dP(d, d) = d,$$ but how do I conclude that $$P(d, d - 1) = P(d, d - 2) = P(d, 1) = P(d, 0) = 0?$$**

I am only taking an introductory module in stochastic processes, so any explanations to the mathematical proof will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The terms in the sum $\sum_{y=0}^d yP(0,y)$ are all non-negative. If the sum is $0$, then each term must be $0$, forcing $P(0,y)=0$ for $y=1,2,\ldots,d$ because $y>0$ for $y=1,2,\ldots,d$. Similar reasoning works for $P(d,y)$, $y=0,1,\ldots,d-1$.

Comment: For $d$, the terms in the sum $\sum_{y=0}^d (d-y)P(d,y)$ are all non-negative. If the sum is $0$ (which is the same as saying that $\sum_{y=0}^d yP(d,y)=d$), then once again each term must be $0$, forcing $P(d,y)=0$ for $y=0,1,\ldots,d-1$ because $d-y>0$ for $y$ in that range.

Comment: Because $\sum_{y=0}^d P(d,y) =1$, so $\sum_{y=0}^d d\cdot P(d,y) =1$. Now split the $(d-y)$ sum into two sums.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Yes! I get it now, but I think there is a typo in your last comment though. Did you mean $\sum^d_{y = 0} dP(d, y) = d$?

Comment: Yes — that $1$ should be $d$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you so much! Would you mind putting all of this into an answer so I can accept it? Your help was exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If we're in state $d$, we can only stay in $d$ or transition to some value *less than* $d$ - that is to say, the probability of increase is 0.  But this is a martingale, so our expected movement must be zero - it follows trivially that the probability of decrease must also be zero, and so the state is absorbing.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but you are not really answering either of the two questions I have. As mentioned in my post, I have no issues intuitively understanding why states $0$ and $d$ are both absorbing. However, I am having issues with the mathematical proofs.

Comment: The proof simply states what I've stated above, in symbolic terms.  You know that the probabilities of transition to other states must be zero, because if they were nonzero you would have a nonzero expectation of movement.  There's nothing more to it than that; you can write it however you want, the logic is the same.